# Python tools/libraries for Semantic Web: state of the art?

Tags: python, semantic-web, inference

What are the best (more or less mature, supporting more advanced logic, having acceptable performance, scalable to some extent) open source Semantic Web libraries and tools (RDF storage, reasoning, rules, queries) for Python nowadays? Historically Python tools (cwm) were among the first to appear, but it still seems that everyone uses Java back-ends for performance and Python as mere client if at all. My purpose is to learn the technology and maybe some future use in production system if it proves itself up to the task. The task is not yet defined, but as I see it its building a knowledge base, linked with some external resources, and customized facet-navigable web front-end.

If some building blocks based on Python are not good enough, then what is the suitable piece from Java/C/C++/whatever world.

Typical stack is also of interest, if there are one or two clear winners.

Thanks.

Comment: A similar question occurred to me. Here is what I found out so far: <https://github.com/cknoll/python-semantic-overview> By the way: I think, this question should be reopened, maybe in community wiki mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A survey of of Python libraries and tools for Semantic Web programming is available [here](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/02/24/survey-of-pythonic-tools-for-rdf-and-linked-data-programming/).  It includes libraries for working with RDF as well as Python-friendly triple stores.

Toby Segaran's book [Programming the Semantic Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596153813) also has a lot of programming examples in Python.

Comment: Thank you! The "Survey of Pythonic tools for RDF and Linked Data programming" is exactly what I was looking after. I only wonder why it never popped high enough while I was searching for "python semantic web"...

Comment: The link has changed. The correct one is:
http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2011/02/24/survey-of-pythonic-tools-for-rdf-and-linked-data-programming/

Answer (score 2):

You could check out the [pyswip](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/). It could work with the [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/index.html). Wish it would fit for requirement. :)

Comment: Thanks! SWI Prolog is quite capable even for large volumes of facts. Hopefully, the power is not limited by bridging to Python.

Comment: Also interesting link, which helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327167/how-to-query-rdf-owl-using-swi-prologs-semantic-web-library

Answer (score 1):

To name some, check out [RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) and [CubicWeb](https://docs.cubicweb.org/index.html).