# Is there a Python Library that 'understands' SKOS, especially the altLabel-/pref-Label-Concept?

Tags: python, semantic-web, ontology, skos

I want to annotate a couple of XML-Files with the [German STW Thesaurus for Economics](http://zbw.eu/stw/versions/latest/about.en.html). You can get the files [here](http://zbw.eu/stw/versions/latest/download/about.en.html) as ZIP-Archives in RDF/XML, N3 and Turtle (~14MB each).

So I wrote a Python-Script that deletes Stopwords, lemmatizes and does Part-of-Speech-Tagging. Now I want to check if a noun in one of the XML-Files is in the STW-Ontology. If yes, I'd like to do different options for a later to be done Automated Classification:

- If it is an `skos:altLabel` Word, replacing it with the `skos:prefLabel` Word
- Do nothing with the text, but add the `skos:prefLabels` at the end of the file with a count of the appearances of the `skos:prefLabel` and the associated `skos:altLabels`
- Using e.g. `skos:broader` to find e.g. the [Economic sectors](http://zbw.eu/stw/version/9.0/thsys/w/about.en.html) or the [Commodities](http://zbw.eu/stw/version/9.0/thsys/p/about.en.html) related to the `skos:prefLabel`.

I know [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) and [Apolda](http://apolda.sourceforge.net/), which are able to do this, but they're Java-based and I'd like to do everything from one Python-Script at the end.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for but for working with RDF you have [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib).

You can get more guidance in the tools/libraries pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779922/python-tools-libraries-for-semantic-web-state-of-the-art) or [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/wiki/Python).

Hope this can help! :)

Comment: The first tests are promising. Thank you!